# python mechanize iterate over select options and submit using lambda

Tags: python, forms, dictionary, lambda, mechanize

I'm trying to write this in the most pythonic way possible, but I'm just now learning about lambda's (and what they can be combined with) and I'm having some difficulty.

Using the `mechanize` module I'm scraping a website for a select control and trying to submit each option value to the form and read the resulting content (maybe I'm trying to do too much for one little 'ol statement).  Here is what I've got:

```
 f = "ctl00$holdSection$selSubAgentFilter" #the select box field name
 self.br.select_form(nr=0) #make the form selection in the browser instance
 #here's where the magic is done
 map( (lambda item,f=f: print(self.br.form.find_control( f ).items[ item[0] ].selected.submit().read() ) ), enumerate( self.br.find_control( f ).items ) )
```

So, to break it apart, I'm trying to do the following:

1. iterate over each of the options in the select field, by using enumerate and getting the items from the control and submitting that enumerated list to the `map` function to basically "walk" over each list item
2. use a lambda function for the `map` executed function
3. submit the items list (enumerated to get indices) to the lambda function
4. using the enumerate index from the passed item, select the item in the form control and select it
5. submit the form
6. read the contents of the new browser window and `print()` it back to the stdout

Of course in this case the `selected` property of the chained methods evaluates to a boolean and emits the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'submit'
```

But you get the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm just not sure how, and accomplish it with a minimal footprint--I can get it to work using several lines and for loops, I was just trying to stay away from that if possible.  I'm trying to branch out and overcome issues in the most pythonic way, rather than the easiest.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most "Pythonic" way is the most readable way. If a for loop is working for you, there is certainly no need to do a map, filter, or lambda.

A decent rule of thumb for when to use list comprehensions, maps, filters, etc, is that if you are working on a list of data, use comprehensions, maps, and filters. If you are doing repetitive logic, like operating on each item in a list, then you can do a for loop.

Example 1: I need to filter out unnecessary data from a list, so I do a comprehension.

```
new_list = [item for item in list if item.has_special_property]
```

Example 2: I need to run some operation for each item in a list, so I do a for loop.

```
for item in list:
    log_important_info(item)
```

These are clearly simplified examples, but I hope you see that Example 1 works on data and Example 2 works on code.

Anyway, I would use a `for item in option` loop, select the appropriate element in the form, and submit it, all within the loop. It will be extremely clear to you and anyone else that reads your code exactly what you are doing, particularly if you comment it.

The code you have written above would be difficult to instantly understand if I came upon it in a project.

If you want to understand what Pythonic really means, then I highly suggest reading [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).